# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee7cceff8)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I meet this problem when I used a custom segue on a button. The code and picture of views that has the problem are attached below. I have been working around this for hours but cannot find the problem. The debugger only outputs "lldb". I do discover that **the problem only happens when I start the app from the root view** (the left most view). If I start the app from UITabBarViewController or UIViewController which contains the segue, the segue performs normally. I am new to swift. Could someone help me please! If you need any more code please ask me.

[Segue code that causes the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgDXx.png)

[View hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEjTT.png)

[Views where problem occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYs6r.png)

Comment: Check your bindings, you probably have an `@IBOutlet` you use in the view controller that isn't binded to anything in your storyboard. That's what I usually get that error for

Comment: No, I don't have an `@IBOutlet` in any of these two scenes. And I still don't get why this problem only occurred when I started from root view.

Comment: If it only occurs when you start from the root view you should look at the root view then rather than the scenes